# Pushing files to production/staging server with GIT

Tags: git

So far i only used GIT to version control my local files, i am now trying to set up a staging environment on a remote server so that later i can push my local development files to the staging server using GIT and eventually to a production server.

So what i did was:

- initallizaed a bare git repository on my staging server
- Added that server as a remove on my local version of the site
- Then ran : `git push origin master`

I get no error message yet the staging repo is empty, well only the .git folder got updated but the actual files didn't follow.

I found a similar question here [Git: Files pushed from local repo not showing up in remote git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219689/git-files-pushed-from-local-repo-not-showing-up-in-remote-git-repo), though i still don't get what i am supposed to do to push my local files?

What would be the proper way to go to achieve this setup ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is what i got so far.

Pushing a git repo to a remote server does not upload the actual files but rather the "blueprint" of these. So once a repo has been uploaded to a remote server, to be able to work on these files you need to clone that repo. After that the workflow is:

1- `Push` the files from local to remote repo (central sort of repo)

2- Cloned instances can `pull` the changes from that repo to stay up to date.

If i got that wrong please correct me.